# Adding first occurrence in a 2D list to another list (Python 3.4.2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, multidimensional-array, enumerate

This is currently my code:

```
num = 0
sav = [["Name: ", "Josh", "Score", "1"], ["Name", "James", "Score: ", "2"], ["Name: ", "Josh", "Score: ", "2"]]
sav2 = [[]*5 for _ in range(len(sav)]
name2 = sav[num][1]

for i, j in enumerate(sav2):
    if name2 not in j:
        sav2.append(sav[num])
        num = num+1
        print('hi')
    else:
        print('hello')
        num = num+1

print(sav2)
```

Ideally, each name and score would go into `sav2` as long as the name wasn't already in there. But, when I run this I get an error - list index out of range  in `sav2.append(sav[num])`. (Note - the `"hi"` and `"hello"` were just there to ensure my if/else statement was working (it was).)

End result:

```
sav2 = [["Name: ", "Josh","Score: ", "1"], ["Name: ", "James", "Score: ", "2"]]
```

Comment: Appending to the list you are iterating over is not the best idea.

Comment: what is `num` and what are you doing to it and why

Comment: Any ideas how I could do this better?

Comment: `num` is just something to increase how far into the list the index is

Comment: but...why aren't you just using i....you have `for i, j in enumerate(sav2)`

Comment: Anyways your problem is that you always increase `num`, but you don't always increase the size of `sav2` to compensate. You never have any way of ensuring that `num` is actually a valid index. BTW, `enumerate` automatically responds to an increase in sequence length, so you really have no need for `num`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason for enumerate, as it doesn't appear the index in the list is important for the outcome.  Just traverse the list, pull out both values, and simply verify that the first value pulled out isn't already in sav2.  You can utilize the else clause on the for loop to accomplish this, in conjuntion with a break statement if a match is found.

```
    sav = [["Josh", "1"], ["James", "2"], ["Josh", "2"]]
    sav2 = []
    for i, j in sav:
        for name, num in sav2:
            if name == i:
                break
        else:
            sav2.append([i,j])
    print(sav2)
```

Comment: I see you altered the contents of sav from when I first started answering.  I don't know why you added Name and Score to the values in the lists, as they don't seem to add anything, however they could be added in to the above for loop if necessary.  The dict answer above is pretty good though.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing them in a dictionary?

```
sav2 = {}
for (name, number) in list_of_lists:
    if name not in sav2:
         sav2[name] = number
```

Resulting in:

```
sav2 = {"Josh":"1", "James":"2"}
```

You could use an OrderedDict if you need to preserve list ordering, and coudl go back to a list of lists if you wanted easily enough:

```
sav2list = [[k,v] for k,v in sav2.items()]
```

Having them in a dictionary will almost certainly help you when you need to add functionality to the code, as you'll probably want to look things up by value, not index.

Comment: Just updated my question to change it slightly - how would I do it like this?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about changing it (though it works fine in my original version)

Comment: If you are using data with lots of fields, why not use a library like pandas that is suited for this?  In anycase, the only difference is that (name, number) becomes (name, field1, field2, number).

Comment: As I am not working on my own computer I cannot download pandas. However, when I try your next solution I get a too many values to unpack error (expected 4)

Comment: Fiddled round with some code too eventually get a dictionary contaning tuples, but it still had all of the names including duplicates